# Angularjs attributes dynamically set from scope not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I unfortunately need to support IE7 and followed the guidlines set out in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

I have an issue when setting attributes from the model like so :

```
<div class="{{someScopeObjectClass}}" >
```

This sets the class correctly in IE8, Chrome but not in IE7.

Similarly, this works in those browsers

```
<input type="button" data-ng-click="someScopeMethod(foo)" 
                                    value="{{someScopeObject.ButtonText}}"/>
```

but in IE7, the `data-ng-click` works fine but the `value` attribute is not being set correctly.

I have tried the following, but have not had any luck so far:

```
<div data-ng-class="{{auditContainerClass}}" >
```

and

```
<div data-ng-attr-class="{{auditContainerClass}}" >
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS has already dropped support for IE7 in version 1.2

If you really need to suport the IE7, you could use an older version, may be 1.1.5

Or consider try this project out: https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-ie7-support